# Wittgenstein. The sense of the world must lie outside the world

Tags: ethics, wittgenstein

I would be grateful if someone could recommend a book, or an article that really tries to get to the bottom of the above statement. Again "The sense of the world must lie outside the world".

Comment: Do you know literature about the [Tractatus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/#EarlWitt)?

Comment: See e.g. Michael Morris, [Wittgenstein and the Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus (Routledge, 2008)](https://books.google.it/books?id=xoFBMAEACAAJ), **Ch 7C Ethics**, page 320-on

Comment: Thanks Mauro. Downloaded it. It is a great metaphysical statement. It needs at least a few pages.

Comment: But W's point of view is quite idiosyncratic: if the language expresses only *facts* of the world and ethics are about *values* and values are **not** facts, that the language cannot "speak of" values.

Comment: If so, every "discourse" about values and meaning (of life) lies outside language. But there is no language "outside of" language... thus, we are left with "the mystical" (the ineffable). Very debatable...

Comment: We do talk about values. And our talk is not useless. But it is impossible to make a coherent system of values. And we wonder about the ground of values. Do they just reside in our brain chemistry? Also to the meaning of events in life. Do they have a meaning? I came across a quote from Jaspers to the effect that meaning cannot be isolated. It must be dispersed, I suppose. Perhaps he means that there are no units of meaning. I cannot find exactly where the quote comes from, but it is along the lines of my thinking. I recommend The Time of the Magicians (Wittgenstein, Heidegger, Cassirer,

Comment: and Benjamin) by Wolfram Eilenberger. It is what prompted me to ask the question. Regards.